# I just started learning Swift, and I am getting this problem wrong in this Lambda School precourse

Tags: swift

Here are the instructions:

" Provided for you is a protocol called Cook. Create two structs or classes that conform to the Cook protocol. In the implementation of the cookSteak function for each struct, print out how that object would cook a steak. For example, if one of your class or structs was a Robot it might use laser vision to cook it."

And here is my code:

```
protocol Cook {
  var user: String
  var style: String
    func cookSteak(){
      print("The " + user + " cooks with " + style".")
    }
}
struct Robot: Cook {
    let user = "robot"
    let style = "laser vision"
    cookSteak()
}
```

I guess my main problem is that I do not yet understand what protocols, functions, and structs are supposed to represent. Am I at least on the right track?

Comment: Is that the code for `Cook` that was provided for you?  I ask because it looks more like a lesson in subclassing than in protocols.

Comment: You don't need to call `cookSteak()` in your `Robot` `struct`. You also need to define how the properties in your `protocol` can be accessed/modified and `protocol`s don't have "implementations" of functionality

Comment: I would recommend, instead, reading through [the Swift Protocols documentation](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=swift+protocol&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) as you are making basic mistakes which would be better solved through appropriate documentation and tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is close but not quite functional, I fixed it so it will compile.  You're on the right track though. There is a lot of reading material out there that can better answer your questions than me, such as Apple's documentations, but I'll give you a basic description of each, a function(aka `func`) is a way to be able perform some code when needed.  A `struct` basically says I have these pieces of data that I want to be able to pass around as one structured item, it also says these are the functions I am capable of.  A `protocol` is a way to describe to indicate that a particular struct, object, or class is able to hold the data or perform the functions declared within the protocol.  If a Robot says that it is a Cook then you know it will be able to hold a user string, a style string, and it is capable of cooking steak, this is because all those things are required for a Robot to call itself a cook.  But a Robot is not limited to being a Cook, it can implement multiple protocols if needed.

```
protocol Cook {
    var user: String { get set }
    var style: String  { get set }
    func cookSteak()
}
struct Robot: Cook {
    var user = "robot"
    var style = "laser vision"
    func cookSteak(){
        print("The " + user + " cooks with " + style + ".")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I lazily took a look through some of the resources for Swift, but I need to definitely spend some more intimate time with it. I see the similarities to java.. I suppose the ":" kind of acts as the "extends" reserved word.

Comment: Sorry, this is a late response but yes, `:` after a class or protocol declaration is the equivalent of java's `extends`, they both are used to declare what a class or protocol inherits from and/or conforms to.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is a protocol extension with a default implementation of `cookSteak`

Unlike the extension the protocol contains only the requirements the adopting class or struct must implement.

```
protocol Cook {
    var user: String { get }
    var style: String { get }
    func cookSteak()
}

extension Cook {
    func cookSteak() {
        print("The " + user + " cooks with " + style + ".")
    }
}

struct Robot: Cook {
    let user = "robot"
    let style = "laser vision"
}

struct YabbaDabbaDoo: Cook {
    let user = "Fred Flintstone"
    let style = "fireplace"
}

let robot = Robot()
robot.cookSteak() // The robot cooks with laser vision.

let fred = YabbaDabbaDoo()
fred.cookSteak() // The Fred Flintstone cooks with fireplace.
```

Please read the [Swift Language Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html). It's worth it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm going to spend some intimate time with that guide for sure.